# Selecting range inside For each loop works fine and but if outside the loop, gives error

Tags: excel, vba

When I select a range inside a for loop, it works fine:

```
For Each d1 In Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))
```

To improve the performance of the code, I tried selecting range outside the For Each loop as follows. But it gives me error.

```
Dim StartCell As Variant
Dim EndCell As Variant

StartCell = Range("B2")
EndCell = Range("B2").End(xlDown)

For Each d1 In Range(StartCell, EndCell)
----
----
```

Can anyone help in resolving the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your two variables are actually ranges so you need to use the Set statement when assigning such (object) variables. Btw your code will fail if you have nothing underneath B2.

```
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim EndCell As Range

Set StartCell = Range("B2")
Set EndCell = Range("B2").End(xlDown)

For Each d1 In Range(StartCell, EndCell)
```